# Реально ли сделать градиент фон как на фото через css?

Tags: html, css

Вот на фото задный фон есть градиент, если можна сделать такой градиент фон через стили css, то помогите плс)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну дайте ссылку на сайт и посмотрим

Comment: @Zhihar Суть в том , что мне скинули  пнг картинку, и есть задача. с верстать  с пнг ,а вот проблема с градиентним фоном. как сделать?)

Comment: из нескольких `div` такое собрать конечно можно, на счет одного css запроса - тут максимум 3 градиента (через `before` и `after`) можно получить, как мне кажется

Comment: @Zhihar, да но я как то не очень шарю в том, чтоб сделать через ксс стили, такой же фон с градиентами))

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo я не знаток но ты на должность Пикассо нанимался? тебе скорее svg в этом деле нужен нежели css